# how do I reinstall the AOSP music player in KitKat?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, music-player

I bought a Motorola Moto G yesterday,
And the stock Android music player is missing. 
I found an old froyo player that works somewhat but it isn't fully integrated.
I can't switch songs from the lock screen or the drop down menu. And it has advertising in it.

Where can I find the AOSP music player that will run fully in KitKat; with total OS integration and no ads?

Answer (score 0):

The Moto G comes with Google Play Music as it's default music player. You can download it from the play store if you don't have it already.

Comment: Actually, Google Play Music is not AOSP music player. This may be a good alternative, but not really a direct solution to the question.